# How to enable debug mode as an option using Python's logging module

Tags: python

Let's say I pass in a parameter of `--debug` to my script where I want it to display additional text when it otherwise doesn't display it by default.

Going to keep it really simple here. How do I get `logger.debug` to display/log? Is it just a matter of "enabling" it if `--debug` is passed?

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

fh = logging.FileHandler('xyz.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)

logger.error("This is an error")
logger.info("Info 123")
logger.debug("FYI, here's what you don't see unless you enable me.")
```

Maybe?

```
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
if option == 'debug'
    logger.debug("FYI, here's what you don't see unless you enable me.")
```

Comment: `if option == 'debug': fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fh = logging.FileHandler('xyz.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG if option == 'debug' else logging.INFO)    
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

To handle arguments which are passed to your script you can use one of bunch libs such as [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) or [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt).

Comment: Thx, sorry I should've mentioned I am using `optparse`, just wasn't sure how to "enable" the debug mode.

Answer (score 5):

Python logging system is quite complex, deserving a question in an interview.

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.debug("FYI, here's what you don't see unless you enable me.")
```

To see the message in, let's say, console you have to:

1. Enable logger of the current module (see `__name__` in the code) or some of the parent loggers (for example the root logger) for level `DEBUG`.
2. Attach a handler for `stdout` to logger of the current module or some of its parents with level `DEBUG`.

Using `dictConfig` is easier to set up the logging configuration:

```
import logging.config


LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
    },
}


logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)

logging.getLogger(__name__).debug('This is a debug message')
```

In the example above you will see the message in the console.

But if you change level of the root logger or of the console handler to `INFO` -- you will not see the message.

You keep the logging configuration in a separate, environment-dependent file.

See also a very useful package when fiddling with logging configuration: http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2012/logging_tree/

Answer (score 2):

It's displaying logging `logger.info` since it's what you set it to do with `fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)`. Use `fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` to register `logger.debug` calls or both depending on option. You can also have multiple Filehandlers if you want to keep `INFO` and `DEBUG` seperate. Remember that your log is stored in xyz.log - if you want to stop logging during runtime call `logger.disabled = True`.